# Is there anyway to center the Column Chart on the xAxis

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts

I just want to center the columns on their xAxis, is there anyway to do this?
this is my code for my highcharts

it looks like the column always started on the tick, i just want to display the column between 2 ticks.

Check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1yds.jpg

```
   Highcharts.chart('YearNS', {
        chart: {
            width: 1200,
            height: 450,
           type: 'column',
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.type, this.name);

            },
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'This Year NS vs Last 4 Years'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view the breakdown by Term. Click again to view by Program. Updated as of ' + MyUpdateDate
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 4,

            categories: categories
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Number of Students"
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            verticalAlign: 'top',

            floating: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {

                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {

                            ParamYear = this.category
                             var res = ParamYear.substring(0, 4);
                          // let urlParams = new URLSearchParams('=');
                            window.location = "http://localhost:37590/NewStudentReportTerm?ParYear="  + res

                        }
                    }
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                pointWidth: 150,
                dataLabels: {
                    //inside: true,
                    overflow: 'none',
                    crop: false,
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:,.0f}',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: false,
                        textOutline: false,
                        color: 'black'
                    },
                }
            },

            column: {
                events: {

                }
            },
        },
        series: series,
        drilldown: {
            series: {
                chartDrilldownData
            }
        }
    });
```

I want th columns to appear in between those lines, in the center of each year. Is that even possible?

Thank you!
edited

here's my Json Data.

```
  [
{
    "New_Students": "321",
    "NSYEAR": "2014",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "1923",
    "NSYEAR": "2015",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "293",
    "NSYEAR": "2016",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "29",
    "NSYEAR": "2017",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
},
{
    "New_Students": "524",
    "NSYEAR": "2018",
    "NSterm": null,
    "NStermCat": null,
    "NSCareer": null,
    "NSProgDescr": null,
    "NSStudent": null
}
    ]
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo Flores, Please provide us with your data structure.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, i just edited my question including my json data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable `grouping` option for the `column` series:

```
 plotOptions: {
     column: {
         grouping: false
     }
 }
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ow8vkq1f/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.grouping

Comment: thank you so much @ppotaczek such a great help! its working!

Comment: i have another question, is it possible to add a spline that will show the increase and decrease number from previous year?

Comment: Hi @Paulo Flores, Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tqnkz0ha/ ?

Comment: exactly! and in addition, it will display as well the increase/decrease of previous column @ppotaczek

Comment: @Paulo Flores, but how you would like to display the increase/decrease of previous column? I think that the best will be if you create a new question with `highcharts` tag.

Comment: thanks ppotaczek :) i wil. this is awesome thank you!

Comment: please help me with this please

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470507/how-do-i-redraw-only-the-highchart-with-new-api-that-depends-on-my-select-option