# how do i redraw only the Highchart with new API that depends on my Select Option Parameter?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, highcharts

im trying to figure out if its possible to redraw the chart based on my parameter that will only call an specific API?

here's the look of my chart upon load.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l33oW.jpg

with the data structure of this using json:

```
[
    {
        "New_Students": "495",
        "NSYEAR": "2018",
        "NSterm": "1801",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "29",
        "NSYEAR": "2018",
        "NSterm": "1802",
        "NStermCat": "2",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    }
]
```

so when the user click on the Year: Dropdown and selected "ALL" the chart should redraw and call the API of this structure :
so the Year will be Year: ALL and Term: All (dropdownlist)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EGEq.jpg

```
[
    {
        "New_Students": "1",
        "NSYEAR": "2013",
        "NSterm": "1301",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "269",
        "NSYEAR": "2014",
        "NSterm": "1401",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "52",
        "NSYEAR": "2014",
        "NSterm": "1402",
        "NStermCat": "2",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "1758",
        "NSYEAR": "2015",
        "NSterm": "1501",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "165",
        "NSYEAR": "2015",
        "NSterm": "1502",
        "NStermCat": "2",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "272",
        "NSYEAR": "2016",
        "NSterm": "1601",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "21",
        "NSYEAR": "2016",
        "NSterm": "1602",
        "NStermCat": "2",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "21",
        "NSYEAR": "2017",
        "NSterm": "1701",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "8",
        "NSYEAR": "2017",
        "NSterm": "1702",
        "NStermCat": "2",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "475",
        "NSYEAR": "2018",
        "NSterm": "1801",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "29",
        "NSYEAR": "2018",
        "NSterm": "1802",
        "NStermCat": "2",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    },
    {
        "New_Students": "20",
        "NSYEAR": "2018",
        "NSterm": "1811",
        "NStermCat": "1",
        "NSCareer": null,
        "NSProgDescr": null,
        "NSStudent": null
    }
]
```

in my code right now it only refresh the page and nothing happens, i tried to create a if statement with the text on the select option but nothing happens :(

here's my code:

```
<script> 
    var strCampus = "<%=MyProperty%>";
     var MyUpdateDate = "<%=UpdateDate%>";
    var ParamTerm;
    var OnClickYearVal;
    var Year = [];

    var myURL = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var ParYear = myURL.get('ParYear');
    console.log(ParYear)

    //$(document).ready(function () {
    //       if (document.getElementById('sel').selectedOptions(0).text == "All") {
    //            var url = 'http://localhost:37590/get_NSDataTerm1/' + strCampus  
    //        } else {
    //            var url = 'http://localhost:37590/get_NSDataTerm/' + strCampus +'/'+ ParYear
    //        }
    //});

    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:37590/get_NSDataTerm1/' + strCampus  , function (jsonData) { 
            const data = jsonData
            console.log(data);

let categories = [],
  series = [],
  i,
  j;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  categories[i] = data[i].NSterm;
  Year = [data[i].NSYEAR]
  series.push({
    name: [+data[i].NSterm] + ' School Year',
    data: [+data[i].New_Students]
  });

  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    series[i].data.unshift(null);
  }
}




Highcharts.chart('TermNS', {
    chart: {
     width: 1150,
     height: 450,
    type: 'column'
    },
    exporting: {enabled: false},
    title: {
        text: 'NS for  ' + Year + 'SY' + ' per Term'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view the breakdown by Career. Click again to view by Program. Updated as of ' + MyUpdateDate
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: "Number of Students"
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: categories.length - 1,
    crosshair: false,
    categories: categories
    },


     legend: {
            enabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            verticalAlign: 'top',

            floating: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
        },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false
        },
            series: {
            borderWidth: 2,
           pointWidth: 80,
            dataLabels: {
                //inside: true,
                overflow: 'none',
                crop: false,
                enabled: true,
                //format: '<span style = "color:{series.color}"</span> : <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
                style: {
                    textShadow: false,
                    textOutline: false,
                    color: 'black'
                },
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                  click: function () {
                      ParamTerm = this.category
                      var CatTerm = ParamTerm.substr(-1);

                      window.location = "http://localhost:37590/NewStudentReportProgram?ParYear="  + ParYear + '&ParTerm=' + CatTerm
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
    },
  series: series
        });
        });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically change chart options you can use `chart.update()` method where new options like `series.data`, `chart.title`, axis options etc can be passed. When only data needs to be changed you can use `series.setData()` or `series.update()`. Check demo and docs posted below to learn more about it.

Demo:

- chart.update(): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v4f862ty/2/
- series.setData(): http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: thanks for the reply @wojciech will try to test this one. im still confuse how to update this with my multiple API's

Comment: do you have any sample with the use if Json Api to call another API and update the chart? thank you

Comment: I don't have so specific example. However, check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p7dta91c/1/. You can update a chart after you retrieve data from the API.